# Flutter ListView into ListView.builder

Tags: android, listview, flutter, dart

I want to convert this ListView into a ListView.builder, because i need the Index. Can someone show me how to cnvert thsi ListView?`Thank for your Help :)

```
return new ListView(
   children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  return new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(document['name']),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can create a ListView builder, which provides an index

```
 var documents = snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document);
    return ListView.builder(
     itemCount: documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => {
       // Just an example, use your own fields
       Text(documents[index].Name);
    });
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You just provide a builder function. This function gets called for each Item in your data. The amount of items you set with itemCount.

Example:

```
var dataList = []; //this would be your snapshot data

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(gallery),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(dataList[index]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```